# Meta-analyses using raw mean as Effect Size, instead of mean differences (e.g., Cohen's d)

Tags: meta-analysis, effect-size

I am writing up my meta-analysis using raw mean scores as effect sizes (i.e., reported mean scores on a certain standardized test) using the `metafor` package in R.

I used the approach discussed in CV  [[Calculation for the estimated sampling variance of individual group raw mean](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/207426/calculation-for-the-estimated-sampling-variance-of-individual-group-raw-mean]), [[Interpreting intercept-only meta-analysis model when effect size is raw mean](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/191144/interpreting-intercept-only-meta-analysis-model-when-effect-size-is-raw-mean])

I would like to cite an article discussing the use of raw mean as ESs that explain the use of the ESs and provides a theoretical background of the weighting (s2/n) (Hox, 2010, p. 209).

Although Hox (2010) was helpful and there are many meta-analyses using raw mean as ESs (e.g., weight change), I could not find a good textbook manner of explanation of raw mean as ES: how to calculate weights, the rationale behind the raw mean ESs, how this ES has been used, what caveats we should note, etc., which we can easily find for ESs of mean differences (e.g., Cohen's d or Hedges' g).

If you know any articles that I can cite to clearly show that raw mean scores can be used as ESs and how statistical approach has been taken, I would love to know.

**Edited** 
I am having difficulty finding meta-analyses using raw mean scores as effect sizes. I would really appreciate it if you could let me know such meta-analyses that explain their approach and their weight calculations.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: As long as you know the sampling variances you can meta-analyse anything you like so I am not sure what extra justification you are seeking.

Comment: Thank you for your response, @mdewey. I apologize for my ambiguous question. What I would like to know is a list of meta-analyses that used raw mean scores as effect sizes and provided (at least moderate) explanations for the use. I revised my question. If you know any meta-analysis, I would really appreciate hearing them. Thank you.

Comment: Raw means and variances are better than ESs, because you now you are using the same units. It's unusual that you can use them though.

Comment: Thank you for you guys' insight, @JeremyMiles and @mdewey. Now I am wondering if meta-analyses using raw mean scores are basically identical to `weighted least squares` (or `weighted linear regression`)? I have been reading into statistics books and found this term, which sounds similar but I am not 100% sure if there are the same as I do not have deep statistical knowledge. I would really appreciate it if I could hear you guys' perspective. Thank you.

Comment: Weighted least squares is equivalent to fixed effects meta-analysis. It's more common to do random effects meta-analysis..

Comment: Oh, I see. And, for a random-effects meta-analysis, effect sizes were weighted using the inverse variance of `tau^2` (population variability in effect sizes) plus `SE^2`!! Now I got a comprehensive understanding of meta-analysis using raw mean scores. Thank you very much, @JeremyMiles!